# Can the same @property present both scalar and collection behavior in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, database, orm, properties, sqlalchemy

I'm converting a library to use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) as the datastore. I like the flexibility of the PickleType column, but it doesn't seem to work well when pickling SA objects (table rows).  Even if I overload setstate and getstate to do a query + session merge when unpickling, there's no referential integrity across that pickle boundary.  That means that I can't query collections of objects.

```
class Bar(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    __tablename__ = 'bars'
    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foos.id'), primary_key=True)

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foos'
    values = Column(PickleType)
    #values = relationship(Bar)  # list interface (one->many), but can't assign a scalar or use a dictionary
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = [Bar(), Bar()]

        # only allowed with PickleType column
        #self.values = Bar()
        #self.values = {'one' : Bar()}
        #self.values = [ [Bar(), Bar()], [Bar(), Bar()]]

# get all Foo's with a Bar whose id=1
session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.values.any(Bar.id == 1)).all()
```

One workaround would be to implement my own mutable object type as is done [here](https://github.com/ccat/sqlalchemy_examples/blob/master/mutable_example/mutable_alwayUpdate.py#L51).  I'm imagining having some kind of flattening scheme which traverses the collections and appends them to a simpler one->many relationship.  Perhaps the flattened list might have to be weakrefs to the pickled collection's objects?

Tracking changes and references sounds like no fun and I can't find any examples of people pickling SA rows anywhere else (perhaps indicative of bad design on my part?). Any advice?

**EDIT 1**:
After some [discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlalchemy/ERtGy5NCtqc/x4PsnsOyGwYJ) I've simplified the request. I'm looking for a single property that can behave as **either** a scalar or a collection.  Here is my (failing) attempt:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Column, Integer, PickleType, String, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import attribute_mapped_collection


# from http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/browser/examples/vertical
from sqlalchemy_examples.vertical import dictlike_polymorphic as dictlike

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Base.metadata.bind = engine
session = Session(engine)


class AnimalFact(dictlike.PolymorphicVerticalProperty, Base):
    """key/value attribute whose value can be one of several types"""
    __tablename__ = 'animalfacts'
    type_map = {#str: ('string', 'str_value'),
                list: ('list', 'list_value'),
                tuple: ('tuple', 'tuple_value')}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    animal_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('animal.id'), primary_key=True)
    key = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String)
    #str_value = Column(String)
    list_value = relationship('StringEntry')
    tuple_value = relationship('StringEntry2')


class Animal(Base, dictlike.VerticalPropertyDictMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'animal'
    _property_type = AnimalFact
    _property_mapping = 'facts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    facts = relationship(AnimalFact, backref='animal',
                          collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('key'))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class StringEntry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stringentry'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    animalfacts_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('animalfacts.id'))
    value = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


class StringEntry2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stringentry2'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    animalfacts_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('animalfacts.id'))
    value = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

Base.metadata.create_all()


a = Animal('aardvark')
a['eyes'] = [StringEntry('left side'), StringEntry('right side')]  # works great
a['eyes'] = (StringEntry2('left side'), StringEntry2('right side'))  # works great
#a['cute'] = 'sort of'  # failure
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PickleType is really a hacky way around edge cases where you have some arbitrary object you'd just like to shove away.     It's a given that when you use PickleType, you're giving up any relational advantages, including being able to filter/query on them, etc.

So putting an ORM mapped object in a Pickle is basically a terrible idea.

If you want a collection of scalar values, use traditional mappings and relationship() in combination with association_proxy.  See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-scalar-collections .

"or dictionaries".  Use attribute_mapped_collection:  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/collections.html#dictionary-collections

"dictionaries plus scalars": combine both attribute_mapped_collection and association_proxy: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#proxying-to-dictionary-based-collections

**Edit 1**:
Well, you dug into a really esoteric and complex example there.    association_proxy is a much easier way to get around these cases where you want an object to act like a scalar, so here's that, without all that crazy boilerplate of the "vertical" example, which I'd avoid as it is really too complex.   Your example seemed undecided about primary key style so I went with the composite version.    Surrogate + composite can't be mixed in a single table (well it can, but its relationally incorrect.   The key should be the smallest unit that identifies a row - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key is a good top level read into various subjects regarding this).

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, Column, create_engine, ForeignKey, ForeignKeyConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Session
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import attribute_mapped_collection
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

Base = declarative_base()

class AnimalFact(Base):
    """key/value attribute whose value can be either a string or a list of strings"""
    __tablename__ = 'animalfacts'

    # use either surrogate PK id, or the composite animal_id/key - but
    # not both.   id/animal_id/key all together is not a proper key.
    # Personally I'd go for "id" here, but here's the composite version.

    animal_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('animal.id'), primary_key=True)
    key = Column(String, primary_key=True)

    # data
    str_value = Column(String)
    _list_value = relationship('StringEntry')

    # proxy list strings
    list_proxy = association_proxy('_list_value', 'value')

    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.str_value is not None:
            return self.str_value
        else:
            return self.list_proxy

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            self.str_value = value
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            self.list_proxy = value
        else:
            assert False

class Animal(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'animal'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    _facts = relationship(AnimalFact, backref='animal',
                          collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('key'))
    facts = association_proxy('_facts', 'value')

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    # dictionary interface around "facts".
    # I'd just use "animal.facts" here, but here's how to skip that.
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.facts.__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.facts.__setitem__(key, value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.facts.__delitem__(key)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return self.facts.__contains__(key)

    def keys(self):
        return self.facts.keys()


class StringEntry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'myvalue'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    animal_id = Column(Integer)
    key = Column(Integer)
    value = Column(String)

    # because AnimalFact has a composite PK, we need
    # a composite FK.
    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint(
                        ['key', 'animal_id'],
                        ['animalfacts.key', 'animalfacts.animal_id']),
                    )
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session(engine)


# create a new animal
a = Animal('aardvark')

a['eyes'] = ['left side', 'right side']

a['cute'] = 'sort of'

session.add(a)
session.commit()
session.close()

for animal in session.query(Animal):
    print animal.name, ",".join(["%s" % animal[key] for key in animal.keys()])
```